# 2.9 Upgrade - fail again

Tags: ee2-upgrades

Of course. When should I do upgrade? at weekdays because of my users. When paid support works? Only business days.
What is problem? Upgrade worked fine, BUT i do get blank screen when I try to enter administration.
I enabled debugging and now I have these errors in admin.php file

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at site/admin.php:1)

Filename: core/EE_Input.php

Line Number: 212
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at site/admin.php:1)

Filename: core/EE_Input.php

Line Number: 212
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at site/admin.php:1)

Filename: core/EE_Input.php

Line Number: 212
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at site/admin.php:1)

Filename: core/EE_Input.php

Line Number: 212
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at site/admin.php:1)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 446

Comment: Do you have any add-ons installed? Did you update them too? Do you have Structure installed?

Comment: There's a another bug you aren't seeing. Disable the [`send_headers`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#send-headers) and try to login again.

Comment: I disabled headers in config.php and still i have same error. In config.php i have $config['allow_extensions'] = "n"; and $config['send_headers'] = 'n';